# Resharper warning

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, resharper

Resharper gives a warning value assigned is not used in any execution path

```
private string FindMyId(string user, string defId) => 
    defId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(defId) ? "defaultvalue" : defId;
```

I created above method to check if a value is empty and assign a default value to it anf return value in the same variable.It works functionaly. But it gives a message from resharper.

Comment: Why are you _assigning_ a new value to `defId`?

Comment: i am trying to return the value to the calling method

Comment: `private string FindMyId(string user, string defId) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(defId) ? "defaultvalue" : defId;` note abscence of `defId = `

Comment: Why are you passing the user string - that isn't used at all?

Comment: @jubi but your parameter is not passed by ref, so reassigning the variable within the method won't change the caller's variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"value assigned is not used in any execution path"

Well, yeah. You reassign the parameter variable `defId`, but because there is only one statement in the method, there's no later method statement to *read* that saved value. In addition, because the `defId` parameter is not pass by ref, that change is only scoped to the method itself.

To get rid of the warning, just remove the variable assignment.

```
private string FindMyId(string defId) => 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(defId) ? "defaultvalue" : defId;
```

As posted, there's no use for the `user` parameter, and the method name `FindMyId` doesn't make logical sense for what the method is doing.